# Tikz, how to give 2 shapes the same height

Tags: tikz-pgf

#### Problem description

Given

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*{\MyNode}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[#1] (A) at #2 {#3};
    \node[isosceles triangle, 
        fill=yellow,
        inner sep=10,
        minimum height=1cm,
        xshift=0.25cm] (T) at (A.east){}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Education}}}
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Work Experience}}}
    
\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

I am trying to find a way to stick 2 shape nodes together and give them equal height.

#### What I have tried

I tried changin the `inner sep` and `outer sep` parameters of the `isoceles triangle` node but that doesn't seem to fix it across all inner-text lengths possibilites. I have further tried to modify the `minimum height` parameter inside the second `\MyNode` instance but that doesn't fix it, and modifying `outer sep` seems to only push the triangle to the right.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: With `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}` you can do e.g. `\node [single arrow, single arrow head extend=0, single arrow tip angle=60, fill=yellow ] {Lorem ipsum};` which doesn't answer the question of making two nodes the same height, but is perhaps a more convenient way of making such a shape.

Comment: Education has no descenders, while Experience does (p).  All you need is to add a \strut to every node (unless you start adding math symbols).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code (and I am not saying this is the best solution): Add an anchor to your triangle for positioning and change the `minimum height` to `minimum width`. While this sound counter-intuitive, it changes the aspect of the triangle you are trying to affect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*{\MyNode}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[#1] (A) at #2 {#3};
        \node[isosceles triangle, 
        fill=blue,
        inner sep=10,
        minimum width=1.4cm,
        anchor=west,
        xshift=-0.02cm
        ] (T) at (A.east){}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.4cm, fill=red]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Education}}}
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.4cm, fill=red]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Work Experience}}}
    
\end{document}
```

I changed the colors for contrast reasons only, feel free to change them back to whatever you need:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is not enterally clear (to me) why you compose shape from two shapes when you can define it with single `signal` shape, where your problem can't happen:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.symbols} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm,
     S/.style = {signal, fill=yellow, signal to=east,
                 minimum height=3ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                 font=\sffamily\bfseries}
                        ]
\node (n1) [S]              {Education};
\node (n2) [right=of n1,S] {Work experience};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, where the tip is just filled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\MyNode}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[#1] (A) at #2 {#3};
    \fill[yellow] (A.north east) -- ([xshift=1.4cm]A.east) -- (A.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Education}}}
    \MyNode[rectangle, inner sep=10, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow]{(0,0)}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{Work Experience}}} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Yellow arrow nodes]